# vb.net string.split vs substring.lastindexof - which is faster or 'better'

Tags: vb.net, string, split, substring, lastindexof

I have a loop that reads through a lot of strings, each string containing information split by a char (¥).
For this loop, i only really need the end value, which i know the index of. I am wondering if it is better to use string.split, or to use substring.lastindexof.

If it helps, the index for split is 8.

Which would be faster.
Also, does my choice of char have any influence on the split? (¥ vs ` vs " for example)

Thanks.

Comment: `lastindexof` should be faster because it searches from end.

Comment: They are 2 different things.  Split splits string, LastIndexOf just tells you where a char is.

Comment: If you alread know the position of your interest there is no need to use split and create an array of string when you need only the last one, Just use substring

Comment: Hi Plutonix. Sorry, i meant using substring with lastindexof

Comment: Steve, is there a method faster than split if i were trying to get a value from say the 3rd instance of the char to the 4th?

Comment: This is something you can test yourself.  Run it a million times each, compare the results.

Comment: Split need to create a bunch of strings that would won't need. But is that really what is slowing down your program?

Comment: It isn't slow as such, but i was wondering which would be faster. I just tested both using a timer and actually found split to be faster. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

People seem to be leaning towards substring(lastindexof) over string.split - i just did a small timer test to see which was faster.

```
For count As Integer = 0 To existing.Count - 1
        If File.Exists(existing(count).Substring(existing(count).LastIndexOf("¥") + 1)) Then 'File.Exists(existing(count).Split(CChar("¥"))(8)) Then
            outputfile.Add(existing(count))
        Else
            outputfile.Add(String.Empty)
        End If
        Next
```

Now the strings in this case are for mp3 tag information, and the path. They typically look like

"Opeth¥Apostle In Triumph Demo¥Apostle In Triumph Demo Part 1¥1:41¥1¥1984¥Progressive Death/Doom/Folk Metal¥¥C:\Users\black\Music\Opeth\Apostle In Triumph Demo\Opeth - Apostle In Triumph Demo Part 1.mp3"

So it checks if the file exists (either using `existing(count).split(cchar("¥"))(8))` or `existing(count).Substring(existing(count).lastindexof("¥") + 1)`) through 8022 strings, then places the value into a list.

Of the 10 times i tested both methods, the split method was always faster - by 32 miliseconds on average, or 2.27% faster.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You are measuring performance of `File.Exists`. Remove it and only measure `LastIndexOf` vs `Split`.

Comment: In case you didn't know, `"¥"c` is the same as `CChar("¥")`.